# TOP N as stored proc parameter without using dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure that returns the top 20 worse percentages. The SP looks something like this:

```
Create procedure dbo.usp_GetAwfulSalesmen
as

select top 20 AvgSales, Name from Sales order by AvgSales ASC
```

But let's say I want to return something other than the top 20.

Is there a way to send the top N to the stored procedure so that it's a parameter instead of a fixed value?

I do not want to use dynamic sql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an INT parameter to your stored procedure (i.e. @Top)

```
Select Top (@Top) AvgSales, Name 
 From Sales 
 Order by AvgSales ASC
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. Thanks.

Comment: @rbhatup Somethings are.  Enjoy them.  They are few and far between